# Has anyone tried merging suppliers in SAP Business One?

Tags: sapb1

In a test database I have tried finding all the card code value in all tables and I was thinking of changing the values in SQL. I know this is not recommended.

Has anyone else faced issues when cleaning up duplicate Suppliers or Customers with transactions and tried Merging them? Other ERP has a solution for this problem, am I missing anything here, because we don't seem to have it in SAP b1.

Created a test database and tried rewriting the old supplier with new values in marketing documents via SQL directly. It worked and I was able to upgrade the database from 9.3 to v10 without any issues or warnings. The only issue I found was that the customer balances were not recalculated. It does allow me to delete one of the duplicate supplier since this SQL will re-map the supplier without breaking anything.